# angular-file-upload: additional properties/options to each file in a multi-file upload?

Tags: angular-file-upload

I'm using nervgh's angular-file-upload, https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API.

Is there a way to use the angular-file-upload and allow additional properties to each file when doing a multi-file upload?

I'm using their image sample to start out with: http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/image-preview/

Trying to add a boolean to each file that the user can set and then I use that on the server side when it's picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`formData`** property shown in [Properties](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API#properties) section to send to server whatever you need.

- ***formData*** {Array}: Data to be sent along with the files.

If you're using PHP in server side, I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831473/sending-additional-values-to-php-script-using-angular-file-upload/31352937#31352937) can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather old, but as the documentation didn't really help me much, I would like to note down my solution here:

**This is how my html looks like (look for "options"):**

```
<div ng-controller="UploadCtrl2" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader" filters="customFilter">
    <div class="progress progress-xs margin-top-5 margin-bottom-20">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                <div class="well my-drop-zone" nv-file-drop=""  options="{formData:[{folder:'attachments'}, {recordid:0}]}" uploader="uploader">
                    Dateien hierher ziehen.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-o btn-file margin-bottom-15"> Dateien auswählen
                    <input type="file" nv-file-select="" options="{formData:[{folder:'attachments'}, {recordid:0}]}" uploader="uploader" multiple  />
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And this is my controller (look for "fileItemOptions"):**

```
app.controller('UploadCtrl2', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'FileUploader', 'Store',
function ($rootScope, $scope, FileUploader, Store) {
    var fileItemOptions = {};
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: $rootScope.app.api.url + '/?c=uploads&a=set&authToken=' + encodeURIComponent(Store.get('X-Xsrf-Token')),
    });
    // FILTERS
    uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'customFilter',
        fn: function (item/*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            if(options) fileItemOptions = options;
            return this.queue.length < 10;
        }
    });
    uploader.removeAfterUpload = true;
    // CALLBACKS
    uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function (fileItem, options) {
        //console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
        if(fileItemOptions.formData) {
            fileItem.formData = fileItemOptions.formData;
        }
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function (addedFileItems) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(uploader);
            uploader.uploadAll();
        }, 500);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteAll = function () {
        $scope.$parent.run.uploadComplete();
        fileItemOptions = {}; // cleanup
    };
}]);
```

Whenever a file is added, the custom filter stores the option object in a global variable. The callback "onAfterAddingFile" will read that variable and it to the fileItem object. Quite hacky, but this was the only way I got it running.